# MySQL - Check if column value (IP) appears in multiple references (orders)

Tags: mysql

This is table structure:
(it's a log)

COLUMNS

```
order id, IP, text, timestamp
```

I have data like this:

```
ORDERREF1 | 192.168.0.1 | Some text about order | TIMESTAMP

ORDERREF1 | 192.168.0.1 | Some text about order | TIMESTAMP

ORDERREF2 | 192.168.0.2 | Some text about order | TIMESTAMP

ORDERREF3 | 192.168.0.3 | Some text about order | TIMESTAMP

ORDERREF5 | 192.168.0.1 | Some text about order | TIMESTAMP

ORDERREF3 | 192.168.0.3 | Some text about order | TIMESTAMP

ORDERREF4 | 192.168.0.4 | Some text about order | TIMESTAMP

ORDERREF2 | 192.168.0.2 | Some text about order | TIMESTAMP
```

As you can see from the data above, one IP appears in two orderrefs.

I need a query that shows me what IP's have appeared in MULTIPLE orderid's and what orderid's they reference.

So results ideally send out like this:

```
ORDERREF1 | ORDERREF5 | 192.168.0.1
```

As that IP is appearing in multiple orderref's its the only result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. This will show the id's and IP's of every IP that has more then one different id's

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(order_id), IP
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT order_id)>1
```

Comment: I have edited my original question with additional details about result request needed

Answer (score 0):

using following query you will get the multiple entries order id with theri
count

```
select *,count(*) as count,group_concat(order_id)
from table_name
group by ip 
having count(*) >1
```

Comment: I have edited my original question with additional details about result request needed

Answer (score 0):

hard to test when i dont have the data, but something like this should work

```
select ip, order_id,
from table_name
group by ip, order_id 
having count(DISTINCT order_id) >1
```

Comment: I have edited my original question with additional details about result request needed